# Bash command for 7zip to convert multiple files into single 7zip files

Tags: bash, 7zip

Trying to convert multiple .odt files to individual  7zip files with password
eg aa.odt and bb.odt to aa.odt.7z and bb.odt.7z with a password of YYY.

Have tried

```
for i in *; do 7z a -pYYY "%i.7z" "%i"; done
```

but it doesn't seem to find any of the files.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Try to replace `%` with`$`

Comment: Thanks. Replacing % with $ generated the names correctly but the 7z archives where empty.

Comment: `for i in *; do 7z a -pYYY "$i.7z" "$i"; done`; I tested in a small test directory and when % was replaced with $ in both places, it works as it should for me.

Comment: Fantastic. That worked brilliantly. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Sudodus solution is great

```
for i in *; do 7z a -pYYY "$i.7z" "$i"; done
```